# Private IP for Istio ingress gateway in AWS

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I am trying to create an Istio ingress gateway with Static private IP via annotation but it does not work. Has anyone created an Istio ingress gateway with a static Private IP in AWS?

**Annotation used via terraform is below:**
`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-private-ipv4-addresses : 10.102.*, 10.101.*`

Comment: Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: istio-ingressgateway
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: istio-system
                   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: true
                   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
                   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-private-ipv4-addresses: 10.105.*
                   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
                   service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: eks-prod